# access_token для осуществления вызовов к серверным методам API VK

Tags: vkontakte-api

Суть проблемы в следующем...

Есть сервер (с++, libcurl). Он обращается за получением `access_token` и получает его (ошибок нет). Но при использовании этого `access_token` в API-методе `secure.checkToken` возникает ошибка:

```
"User authorization failed: access_token was given to another ip address."
```

Пользовательский токен оффлайновый. И если я захожу по ssh на сервер и генерирую из консоли `access_token`, то при проверке ошибок не происходит.

В чем может быть разница между программным получением `access_token` и получением его из консоли, что возникает подобная ошибка?

P.S.: в FB получение `access_token` аналогично и работает последующая проверка без проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Оказывается, если отправлять запрос из консоли, то по какой-то причине запрос идет через интерфейс с ip4. А если тот же запрос отправляется программно, то он идет через интерфейс с ip6. "Убрал" в настройках на сервере ip6 и все заработало.